# Order of messages are not preserved in rsyslog-omkafka module

Tags: apache-kafka, rsyslog

**Architecture:**
File -> imfile -> omkafka -> Kafka topic with single partition -> consumer

Content of file is static. It does not change at all. I assumed that omkafka pushes data to kafka broker in orderly fashion. But it does not.

**Is there any way to configure rsyslog to send files in order ?**

If a producer pushes message to a single partition then ordering of messages are guaranteed by Kafka. Hence, it seems like omkafka module has messed up with the ordering.

Comment: Unless the connection is lost there should be no re-ordering, given you have a modern version of librdkafka (>=v0.11.6).

Comment: I do have latest version of librdkafka. I was able to get proper ordering by 1. configuring max in-flight request to 1. I also found later on that my conusmer was multi-threaded; so I configured it to use a single thread. I was able to preserve the ordering of messages.

Answer (score 0):

Omkafka uses **librdkafka** behind the scene which does not support exactly-once delivery yet (https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/1308). Once this issue gets fixed then I will check it again.

Comment: The upcoming v1.0.0 of librdkafka adds support for the idempotent producer, which guarantees ordering.